# Swift: How to hide "SIRI Found IN APPS" option from CNContactPickerViewController search option?

Tags: ios, swift

I have scenario where I want to fetch all contacts from my contact book and display in my app. I am achieving it successfully using "CNContactPickerViewController",but when I search data it shows search found by siri. I want to avoid it. Is there anyway to do it?